# Wrong layout top and bottom on iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar

my issue is as the below picture. It's good for iOS 8 but when i build on iOS7, the black area appears. Do you know any reason?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check If you miss launch screen file here

[image]

If it does not miss,click **Use Asset Catalog**,then  **Click migrate**

[image]

Comment: You're right! I added the launch images but on iOS 7, it is not loaded.

Comment: I am sorry, not yet. I don't understand why it's not loaded on iOS 7 although I added it to asset catalog.